# Convert Opencv hsv equivalent to Matlab Hsv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have to develop android code using opencv,code equivalent to MATLAB.
In that I have to read an image and convert it to HSV and I have done this using :

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, hsv   , Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

and when I am iterating over each pixels value of pixel returned in range of 0-255 of Hue ,where in Matlab it returns in range of 0-1 , I dont know how to write an equivalent code for it .
I am a beginner.I dont know much about image processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range of values of RGB images is, obviously in [0, 255]. For HSV images it depends on the image type (see [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)):

- **8 bit** images: H in [0, 180], S,V in [0, 255]
- **32bit** images: H in [0, 360] ,S,V in [0,1]

So, after you convert to HSV

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

you need to scale the H and S,V values differently. You can use [split](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#split(org.opencv.core.Mat,java.util.List)) and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#merge(java.util.List,org.opencv.core.Mat)) to get the different channels matrice, and apply correct scaling.

Note that OpenCV stores RGB images as BGR, so you probably need `COLOR_BGR2HSV`.

---

You can split and merge like:

```
List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
Core.split(hsv, planes);
// Scale each single plane
Core.merge(planes , hsv);
```

Comment: can you help me how I can split and merge channels ,please share a reference link for that,if you have any. Thank-you so much.

Comment: @Varun updated the answer. I'm not entirely sure since I don't program in Java, but should work fine. Please let me know.

Comment: "apply correct scaling." - Hey can you guide me a bit on how to apply the scaling?

Comment: @Solace, once you split the channels, just multiply each Mat into planes for the correct scaling factor

Answer (score 2):

255 is 1.0, 128 is 0.5 and so on. just divide n/255 to get Matlab HSV values

Comment: thanx @smirnov ,this helped me.