# In an app using OpenCV4Android, how to find out if the camera is taking 8-bit image or 32-bit image?

Tags: opencv, hsv, color-space, android

In OpenCV HSV images, the scale of Hue depends on the type of image. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932759/convert-opencv-hsv-equivalent-to-matlab-hsv#32933544),

> For HSV images it depends on the image type (see OpenCV doc):
>
> 8 bit images: H in [0, 180], S,V in [0, 255]
>
> 32bit images: H in [0, 360] ,S,V in [0,1]

I have two questions:

1. How do I know which type of image or frame (whether 8-bit or 32-bit) is the camera detecting, e.g. how would I know in [this class](https://github.com/nehiljain/opencv4android/blob/master/samples/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java) in the Color Blob Detection sample application?
2. Is there a way to force the camera to take 32 bit image (because I really want the second scale, and if there is no way, I will have to find a way to convert the first scale to the second one, because [Android's `Color.HSVToColor` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor(int,%20float[])) follows the second scale)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It uses `CvType.CV_8U` so that means 8 bit unsigned.

2) Probably not, you have to dive in the part of code that actually controls the camera and grabs a frame to find this out. However, you can simply convert a 8 bit image to 32 bit by using `convertTo` functions.